# Content not appearing in colorbox AND mobile responsive colorbox?

Tags: image, slider, lightbox, colorbox

I am using a responsive image slider which I am trying to put inside a colorbox however firstly when the colorbox pops up, it opens a blank tiny content box, I want the image slider to appear within the colorbox. The content opens up fine in the colorbox live on my site so can't understand why I can't replicate this in the fiddle.

Secondly, it seems that colorbox doesn't adapt it's size as the browser window is shrunk, is this something that can be changed? I tried setting max-height and max-width in colorbox.js to 100% but that doesn't make any difference.

I have spent most of yesterday trying to sort this but had no luck so far so any help you could give would be appreciated.

The HTML:

```
<a class="colorbox-link fade_hov" href="#port1">Click to open colorbox</a>

<div style="display: none;">
                            <div id="port1">
<div>     
    <div id='ninja-slider'>
        <ul>
            <li><div data-image="http://www.yourdesignpartner.co.uk/dev/wp-content/themes/colorroom/ninja-slider/img/md/1.jpg"></div></li>
            <li><div data-image="http://www.yourdesignpartner.co.uk/dev/wp-content/themes/colorroom/ninja-slider/img/md/2.jpg"></div></li>
            <li><div data-image="http://www.yourdesignpartner.co.uk/dev/wp-content/themes/colorroom/ninja-slider/img/md/3.jpg"></div></li>
            <li><div data-image="http://www.yourdesignpartner.co.uk/dev/wp-content/themes/colorroom/ninja-slider/img/md/4.jpg"></div></li>
            <li><div data-image="http://www.yourdesignpartner.co.uk/dev/wp-content/themes/colorroom/ninja-slider/img/md/5.jpg"></div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
```

The CSS and JS is linked to externally in this Fiddle [THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hCTXx/) [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c9uTd/) without the colorbox which, as you can see, is responsive.

So I just need a way of being able to click a link which opens up the slider in a popup window, if there are any other options or perhaps a mobile responsive lightbox available please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Used fancybox instead of colorbox which it seems is fully responsive to mobile so problem solved.